# Ordering a List<String> by matched Enum's name value

Tags: c#, linq, list, enums, matching

A little unsure of how to do this. I need to display a list of files in a different order than they are presented on our file server.

I was thinking one way would be to order a list of strings by a matched enum's name value.

Let's say I have a full list of strings:

```
    List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
```

And I have a related enum to show the files in a certain order:

```
    public enum ProcessWorkFlowOrder 
    {    
       File1,
       File3,
       File2           
    }
```

The "filenames" string value in the List will match exactly the Enum's name.

What is the best way to match and order the FileNames list by its matched enum value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the filenames match exactly, I wouldn't use an enum but rather another order-preserving list.

```
List<string> namesInOrder = ...
List<string> files = ...

var orderedFiles = from name in namesInOrder
                   join file in files 
                   on name equals file
                   select file;
```

`Join` preserves the order of the first sequence and will therefore allow you to use it to order the second.

Comment: I agree with Anthony. Enum.ToString() seems nice as long as you don't obfuscate your code. Once you obfuscate, any code that used the Enum.ToString() will cease to function.

Comment: Brian: (1) Not everybody needs to obfuscate, and (2) when you obfuscate you can choose not to obfuscate a specific enum's fields.

Comment: Sure, all that's true. I wanted to point out a gotcha with using Enum.ToString() and obfuscation. Especially because he didn't specify if the code was obfuscated or not.

Comment: not obfuscated, but thanks for the comments, and Anthony I like your answer just tried it out and it works perfectly. If anyone does have a way to do it through the Enum name, that'd be cool to see?

Comment: @ProgRockCode I think my answer matches the original brief or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the enum and you can't change it to a list of string like Anthony suggests, you can use this:

```
var order = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProcessWorkFlowOrder))
                .OfType<ProcessWorkFlowOrder>()
                .Select(x => new {
                                   name = x.ToString(),
                                   value = (int)x
                        });

var orderedFiles = from o in order
                   join f in filenames
                   on o.name equals f
                   orderby o.value
                   select f;
```

Comment: Looks promising but I'm getting 'System.Array does not contain a definition for Select'

Comment: This uses Linq; add a `using System.Linq;` to the top of the file.

Comment: if adding using `System.Linq` doesn't help try casting this way: `Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProcessWorkFlowOrder)).Cast<ProcessWorkFlowOrder>().Select(...`

Comment: @danyolgiax: That's unnecessary - you can see the lambda works perfectly fine when it accepts an `Object` - it does the casting when getting the value.

Comment: very strange! Without that cast my code won't compile! `System.Array does not contain a definition for Select...` error!

Comment: @danyolgiax: Thinking about it some more, you're right. `IEnumerable` isn't extended by `System.Linq`, except to include `Cast` and `OfType`. I was mistaking it for `IEnumerable<object>`. Sorry, I'm a little bit rusty - haven't touched C# for quite a while now.

Comment: I've now edited my code to be correct, with `OfType` making sure the enumeration is typed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

how about?

```
var orderedFilenames = filenames.OrderBy(
    f => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProcessWorkFlowOrder), f));
```

However, I'm not sure that maintaining this enum is the best approach, better to write a function to define the order algorithm, what if enum does not contain the file name.

**EDIT** with TryParse

```
var orderedFilenames = filenames.OrderBy(f => {
       ProcessWorkFlowOrder parsed;
       int result = 0;
       if (Enum.TryParse<ProcessWorkFlowOrder>(f, out parsed))
           result = (int)parsed;
       return result;
    });
```

What rules would you use to construct the enum or an order preserving list or, is the order purely arbitary?

Comment: If any file won't have a valid enum value this will crash and burn; since enum doesn't have TryParse you can't easily filter these out without an extra step: `Select(f => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ProcessWorkFlowOrder), f))`

Comment: @configurator, totally agree but, that is essentially the problem with using a enum to derive the order. However a TryParse is available.